# pyfakefs fixture causes pandas.read_csv() to fail in pytest

Tags: pandas, pytest, pyfakefs

I am using `pandas` `read_csv()` function to read some CSV content and want to use "high" or "round_trip" floating-point precision.

The following works in the Python REPL or running a program with the python interpreter dircectly.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv( StringIO('0.00042119645,3.4,8.8244e-5\r\n'), float_precision='round_trip' )
```

If I put in a `pytest` test it also works :)

However, if I use the `pyfakes` fixture then it fails !!  For some reason the `pd.read_csv()` function uses the `python` engine instead of the default `C` engine.  This is true even if I explicitly set `engine='c'`.

The error reported is:

```
ValueError("The 'float_precision' option is not supported with the 'python' engine")
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def test_pandas_read_csv(
        #mocker,     #! pytest-mock test fixture
        fs,         #! pyfakefs test fixture
        ):
    try :
        df = pd.read_csv( StringIO('0.00042119645,3.4,8.8244e-5\r\n'), float_precision='round_trip' )
        assert True
    except Exception as exc:
        assert False
```

How do I use the pandas `read_csv()` function with the default `c` engine in my `pytest` tests that also require the `pyfakes` fixture?

Here is my pytest code.  The tests fail - comment out the `fs,` line to get it to pass all tests.

```py
import pytest

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

class Test_Pandas_Read_CSV :

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
            'csv_str,kwargs,exp_status',
            [
                (
                    ('0.00042119645,3.4,8.8244e-5\r\n'),    #! csv_str
                    dict(                                   #! kwargs
                        float_precision='round_trip',
                        # engine='c',
                    ),
                    True,                                   #! exp_status
                ),
                (
                    ('0.00042119645,3.4,8.8244e-5\r\n'),    #! csv_str
                    dict(                                   #! kwargs
                        float_precision='round_trip',
                        engine='c',
                    ),
                    True,                                   #! exp_status
                ),
                (
                    ('0.00042119645,3.4,8.8244e-5\r\n'),    #! csv_str
                    dict(                                   #! kwargs
                        float_precision='round_trip',
                        engine='python',
                    ),
                    False,                                  #! exp_status
                ),
            ]
        )
    def test_pandas_read_csv(
            self,
            # mocker,                                         #! pytest-mock test fixture
            fs,                                             #! pyfakefs test fixture
            csv_str     : str,
            kwargs,
            exp_status  : bool,
        ) :

        try :
            df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv_str), **kwargs )
            status = True
        except Exception as exc:
            status = False

        assert status == exp_status
```

Comment: I upgraded (`pip install -U pandas`) to the latest `pandas` (1.3.5), which also upgrade `numpy` (1.21.6) and the tests now pass.

I have/had `pandas` (0.23.3) and `numpy` (1.16.2) installed as site-packages on my Debian 10 Buster box.  This is what is actually used on the target device, so I would prefer to also run my pytests with those versions.  Not sure if that's possible now?

Comment: The minimum version of `pandas` that works is 1.3 (1.3.5), which requires `numpy` >= 1.17.3.

Comment: I have a work-around that involves mocking the `pandas.read_csv()` call with a function that first pops the `float_precision` key from the keyword arguments, and then calls the proper/original `pandas.read_csv()` function.  I wrapped that in a customized `pyfakes` fixture to do the mocking.

Though this makes the tests pass, I am concerned that the real C based functions aren't being called and thus the results may vary from what would run on the real target.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround involves mocking the `pandas.read_csv()` call with a function that first pops the `float_precision` key from the keyword arguments, and then calls the proper/original `pandas.read_csv()` function. I wrapped that in a customized pyfakes fixture to do the mocking.

Though this makes the tests pass, I am concerned that the real C-based functions aren't being called and thus the results may vary from what would run on the real target.

```py
orig_pandas_read_csv = pd.read_csv

def mock_pandas_read_csv( *args, **kwargs ):
    kwargs.pop('float_precision', None)
    return orig_pandas_read_csv( *args, **kwargs )


@pytest.fixture
def my_fs(mocker, fs):
    mocker.patch.object( pd, 'read_csv', new=mock_pandas_read_csv )
    yield fs

...

    def test_pandas_read_csv(
            self,
            # mocker,                                         #! pytest-mock test fixture
            my_fs,                                          #! pyfakefs test fixture (with mocked pandas functions)
            csv_str     : str,
            kwargs,
            exp_status  : bool,
            ) :
        try :
            df = pd.read_csv( StringIO(csv_str), **kwargs )
            status = True
        except Exception as exc:
            status = False

        assert status == exp_status
```